# file read and for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this file:

```
-0
1
16
9
-00
1
3
4
0
7
9
-000
...
```

and I want to sort them and store them to a file.

I read the file store them inside a list , sort the list and then save the list to a file. Problem is that It starts from the second -x .

```
 for line in file:
        temp_buffer = line.split()
        for i,word in enumerate(temp_buffer):
            if "-" not in word:
                if word in index_dict:
                    l1.append(word)
                else:
                    l1.append(function(word))
            else:
                l1.append(word)
                l1.sort()
                print(l1 , file=testfile)
                del l1
                l1 = []
```

So the 1st loop it goes to the else statment and stores just the first -0 without the words beween -0 and -00. How should I fix this ?
I want the output to be like that :

```
-0
1
9
16
-00
0
1
3
4
7
9
-000
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to "partition" the data into groups between lines starting with `-` instead. Where it starts with `-` write the line out, otherwise, write the sorted lines, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
  for k, g in groupby(fin, lambda L: L.startswith('-')):
    if k:
      fout.writelines(g)
    else:
      fout.writelines(sorted(g, key=int))
```

Comment: will this sort the list in every loop ? because i need to keep the complexity low.

Comment: It will sort the items between each line starting with `-`

Comment: input file is huge so i need to group the elements and when the group is full(all the elements between -x -xxxx) then store it to the file. will this function try to read all the file and try to group it and then store it ?

Comment: @Bill no... it will consume and sort the parts between the `-`'s as it goes... It will only have in memory the lines between a single set of markers at any one time

Answer (score 0):

You may use this :

```
l1=[]
for i,word in enumerate(temp_buffer):
            if "-" in word:
                l1.sort()
                print(l1)
                l1 = []
            if word in index_dict:
                l1.append(word)
            else:
                l1.append(function(word))
```